# Animating status bar iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, statusbar

Im trying (struggling) to implement a snapchat like error message display for my app (snapchat error messages slide down over the status bar somehow) in iOS7. I cannot for the life of me get my animation to work right. Here is my method that does the animation

```
- (void)animateHeaderViewWithText:(NSString *)text {

    //add header views
    [self.headerView addSubview:self.headerLabel];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.headerView];

    //Hide the Status Bar
    statusBarHidden = TRUE;
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

    self.headerLabel.text = text;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        self.headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
        self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:5.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        //UnHide the Status Bar
        statusBarHidden = FALSE;
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

        self.headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 20);
        self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 20);



    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


        [self.headerView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.headerLabel removeFromSuperview];

    }];
}];

}
```

Only the second half of the animation really works right, the message slides back up fine and the status bar appears underneath it. However, the first half of the animation, when the view slides down, the status bar disappears causing my navigation bar to move up, screwing up my animation. How can I get my navigation bar to stay where it is initially placed, even when the status bar is gone

Comment: Calling `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` method leads to redraw the view and move your navigation bar to top. Find a workaround without doing that.

Comment: Do you need this to work in both portrait and landscape?

Comment: only portrait @rdelmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked in portrait, but would need to be modified to work properly in both orientations. It uses a separate UIWindow as the overlay, so there's no need to hide or unhide the status bar.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIWindow *dropdown;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *label;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIWindow *win;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.dropdown = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 20)];
    self.dropdown.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.dropdown.bounds];
    self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.dropdown addSubview:self.label];
    self.dropdown.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
    [self.dropdown makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.dropdown resignKeyWindow];

}

- (IBAction)dropDown:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self animateHeaderViewWithText:@"This is my test string"];
}


-(void)animateHeaderViewWithText:(NSString *) text {
    self.label.text = text;
    CGRect frame = self.dropdown.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        self.dropdown.frame = frame;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        ;
    }];
}
```

Comment: this works, however the the user cant use the navigation bar while the animation is running. Is there any way I can only use the snapshot of the status bar, and not the whole navigation bar, or just a portion of the nav bar? @rdelmar

Comment: actually they cant do anything while the animation is running since the snapshot takes up the whole screen. If only I knew how snapchat did it. This seems impossible haha

Comment: @Stonep123, do you really need them to do anything during that time? What duration do you want the animation to run over?

Comment: @Stonep123, I've changed my answer to use a UIWindow as the overlay, which should allow the users to still interact with the view.